# What this unix command do 'who | grep “Milad” > /dev/null'?

Tags: shell, dev-null

I want to know what is this command do?

In addition, the 'who | grep > /dev/null' in this loop why must return true or false:

```
until who | grep “Milad” > /dev/null
do
   sleep 60
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will wait until a user named "Milad" is logged in.

`who` gets the list of logged in users, `grep "Milad"` filters the list returned by `who` for entries that contain `Milad`. This will return "true" if the entry was found. To suppress any output, it is redirected to the digital toilet (`> /dev/null`). The whole thing then loops while there is no user `Milad`, sleeping 60 seconds between each test.